# Fat gain/shape after liposuction

Tags: body-fat, fat, bellyfat, skin

I have learned a few facts about the human body over the years and there seems to be some contradiction.

-Fat cells never go away, even when you burn the energy within them. They only shrink in size when their energy stores are used up. Once fat cells are created, you have them for good.

-lipo suction removes the fat cells forcibly, circumventing the above issue, as least on a small scale. I.e only the fat that is not interweaving in your body and could cause damage if removed.

- after lipo, over eating again would cause other areas of your body to gain weight first before the lipo areas.
- fat can still grow back in the lipo areas.

Okay so my question is how to properly reconcile all these facts and/or cut out what is fiction. In short my questions are:

- considering how easy it is for a non-lipo adult to gain weight back after being over weight, is it just as easy to get back into your previous shape after lipo?
- put another way, if you lipo off your lower belly fat (currently it's the first spot to gain the weight and the last spot to lose) will the lower belly fat be the first place to come back after lipo if you eat a lot?

How will the lower belly react to excessive food?

- what does one do about excessive skin after lipo?

I may have other questions but this is good for now. I am a Caucasian male in early 30s.

Comment: This is more of a cosmetic rather than a fitness related question.  Liposuction is a procedure to reduce local areas of fat for appearance sake. They use compression garments afterwards to compress the skin to your new shape. If you gain weight after liposuction, the fat cells that were not removed can still increase in size.

Comment: I understand that the fat cells not removed can increase in size, but would the body create new fat cells where the lipo removed the old?

Comment: This [site on liposuction](http://www.liposuction.com/realistic-expectations.html) says that the body can create new fat cells where the lipo removed fat cells with an increase of more than 10% of body weight.  The site's faq should answer all your questions about lipo.

Answer (score 1):

The body is a funny thing. There is no real way to predict how and where it will store fat. The one observation I have made with my own body is that I typically lose fat first from the places I have most recently put it on. The hardest places to lose it are the places that have had it the longest.

I am sure you have heard that you cannot spot reduce. This is very true. I wouldn't sit around worrying about it. Anxiety leads to excess cortisol production which leads to fat gain. Try and get pro-active with your diet and exercise instead. Sitting around thinking never did anyone any good.

In terms of the excess skin, that is due to a loss of elasticity. I don't think there is much you can do about that outside of getting a tummy tuck. On a positive note, the leaner you get the less that skin will appear 'loose'.

I hope that helps,

Mike